# Time Trigger a function in Google Sheets

Tags: function, time, triggers, updating

I posted the following a few days ago but the answer I received was removed. I am trying again...

In a Google Sheet, the values in column C of sheet 'Daily' are automatically copied and updated from cell C4 in sheet 'Current.'

I would like the value corresponding to each day (in sheet 'Daily') to stop updating at the end of the day.

OR:

Could the value in C4 of 'Current' get copied (without future updating) at a certain time each day in the cell corresponding to that day in 'Daily'?

I hope I wrote this clearly enough. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help or direct me to the right place.

Best,

Lambert

I did not try anything yet because I have no idea where to start. I guess I should learn scripting, but time is short right now...